# Initialize database connection and hibernate session on Jersey startup

Tags: hibernate, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am trying to build an application which is a pure REST API based app without any servlets.
I am using hibernate for ORM purpose. I want to create a hibernate sessionFactory(or a database connection) upon jersey app start-up. From that point forward, whenever there is a need for a hibernate session, a utility class will return a new session.

I am aware of doing this in Spring but how would you achieve this in Jersey? I couldn't find any straight forward reference or documentation for this.

Comment: It kind of depends, I think, on what framework, if any, you are running it on? Spring will use ContextLoaderListener. No framework, just `new` your DAO. So on and so forth.

Comment: Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();